# Issues with CakePHP AuthComponent

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm having issues with CakePHP's AuthComponent.

Here is the complete scenario.

- The app runs on Nginx, CakePHP 2.3 and MySQL.
- The nginx server has a 301 redirect which redirects users from domain.com to www.domain.com.

The user login works well when the host is domain.com and does not work when the host is www.domain.com. After a bit of googling I found out that this was a security feature from CakePHP. Turns out that it forces the  `session.referer_check to true`

There are a few solutions on stackoverflow and other sites too, but using old CakePHP versions and it does not work with my cake app.

This issue has taken a day already!

Please share your experiences?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have redirection setup from domain.com to www.domain.com in the webserver that redirection would happen even before the request reaches php. So how is a user able to login with host domain.com, he should be already redirect to www.domain.com

Comment: @ADmad if I remove the 301 redirection it works. But if I redirect to www.domain.com then the logins don't work.

Answer (score -1):

what are you using to store your sessions in?  I suggest letting cake handle them by changing to 'cake' from 'php' in the core.php

Comment: I am using php `Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'my_app',
    'timeout' => 4320 //3 days
));`

Comment: yes and your GC from PHP could be causing the issue thus my recommendation of changing to cake instead of php for sessions.